# Is there a way to check emr cluster status using cluster name in boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

In the following codes, it can check the EMR status using EMR id:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('emr')
response = emrClient.describe_cluster(ClusterId='j-XXXXXXXX')
```

I find there is no api to query emr status using emr name. But, I have emr name only. How can I check my emr status using emr name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [`list_clusters`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.list_clusters) method you can use to list all existing clusters, filter out the cluster you're looking for by name and receive its id to use for `describe_cluster`.

That'd look like:

```python
import boto3

cluster_name = 'name_of_your_cluster'

client = boto3.client('emr')

clusters = client.list_clusters()
your_cluster = [i for i in clusters['Clusters'] if i['Name'] == cluster_name][0]
response = client.describe_cluster(ClusterId=your_cluster['Id'])
```

Note that this will only work if your EMR clusters have unique names.

Comment: you can also look it up with the unique JobFlowId